# How to visualize 3D voronoi tesselation in python?

Tags: python, voronoi

I have a set of 3D points which I've used scipy.spatial.Voronoi to do the tessellation.
I would like to plot them above the image from which I extracted them.
In 2D case my code was:

```
vor = Voronoi(points) 
voronoi_plot_2d(vor,show_points=True,show_vertices=False, line_colors='red',line_width=0.5,point_size=1)
plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
plt.xlim((-0.5,dim_img-0.5))
plt.ylim((dim_img-0.5,-0.5))
```

How can I achieve the same result but in 3D?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had the same question and couldn't find a satisfactory solution, I looked into plotting 3D Voronoi diagrams with Python myself. Here is what I came up with.

A convenient way of creating such a plot is using pyvoro (https://github.com/joe-jordan/pyvoro), since it correctly cuts the Voronoi cells at the edges of your plot region and directly provides the edge coordinates of the polygon faces. The result can be plotted using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import pyvoro
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
# initialize random number generator
rng = np.random.default_rng(11)
# create a set of points in 3D
points = rng.uniform(size=(15,3))

# use pyvoro to compute the Voronoi tessellation
# the second argument gives the the axis limits in x,y and z direction
# in this case all between 0 and 1.
# the third argument gives "dispersion = max distance between two points
# that might be adjacent" (not sure how exactly this works)
voronoi = pyvoro.compute_voronoi(points,[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]],1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# for each Voronoi cell, plot all the faces of the corresponding polygon
for vnoicell in voronoi:
    faces = []
    # the vertices are the corner points of the Voronoi cell
    vertices = np.array(vnoicell['vertices'])
    # cycle through all faces of the polygon
    for face in vnoicell['faces']:
        faces.append(vertices[np.array(face['vertices'])])
        
    # join the faces into a 3D polygon
    polygon = Poly3DCollection(faces, alpha=0.5, 
                               facecolors=rng.uniform(0,1,3),
                               linewidths=0.5,edgecolors='black')
    ax.add_collection3d(polygon)
    
plt.show()
```

[3D Voronoi Tessellation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMjVF.jpg)

If you don't want to use pyvoro and it's only about creating a plot, you can also do a nearest-neighbor interpolation on a dense 3D grid and create a convex hull around each cloud of points that is within a single Voronoi cell. Note that this works, since Voronoi cells are always convex. Of course, this approach is not quite exact, since there will always remain a little gap between the polygons. An example, continuing from the above code, is given here:

```
# import KDTree for the nearest neighbor interpolation
from scipy.spatial import KDTree, ConvexHull

# create a densely spaced grid in the plot region
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.linspace(0,1,100)
z = np.linspace(0,1,100)
X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)
gridpoints = np.column_stack((X.flatten(),Y.flatten(),Z.flatten()))
# do the nearest neighbor interpolation
kdt = KDTree(points)
nndist,nnidx = kdt.query(gridpoints)
# nnidx gives the index of the Voronoi nucelus for each point in the grid

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# now cycle through all Voronoi indices
for voronoi_idx in np.unique(nnidx):
    idx_polygon = nnidx==voronoi_idx
    # create a convex hull around the point cloud
    hull = ConvexHull(gridpoints[idx_polygon])    
    polygon = Poly3DCollection(hull.points[hull.simplices], alpha=0.5, 
                               facecolors=rng.uniform(0,1,3),
                               linewidths=0.5,edgecolors='gray')
    ax.add_collection3d(polygon)
    
plt.show()
```

[Alternative 3D Voronoi tessellation from convex hull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WWs5.jpg)

You can see that, due to the triangulation, there are a lot of extra lines (you can remove them from the plot by removing the 'edgecolors' keyword).

In the previous plots, you can of course easily add markers for the Voronoi nuclei using

```
ax.plot(points[:,0],points[:,1],points[:,2],'ko')
```

If you don't like the looks of the matplotlib plots, you can use the plotly library and reproduce the above plot.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
for voronoi_idx in np.unique(nnidx):
    idx_polygon = nnidx==voronoi_idx
    hull = ConvexHull(gridpoints[idx_polygon])
    fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(x=hull.points[hull.vertices,0], 
                            y=hull.points[hull.vertices,1],
                            z=hull.points[hull.vertices,2],
                            alphahull=0, # 0 means convex hull
                            opacity=1,
                            color="#%06x" % rng.integers(0, 0xFFFFFF)))

fig.write_html("Voronoi_3D_2.html", auto_open=True)
```

[3D Voronoi using plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn6Gz.png)

Finally, I also tried to create a plot from the scipy.spatial.Voronoi class, but I wasn't successful, since not all vertices are defined (mostly those, that are outside the area defined by the input points).

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi

vor = Voronoi(points)

polygons = []
for ri,region in enumerate(vor.regions):
    # only plot those polygons for which all vertices are defined
    if np.all(np.asarray(region)>=0) and len(region)>0:
        poly = []
        for rv in vor.ridge_vertices:
            if np.isin(rv,region).all():
                poly.append(vor.vertices[rv])
        polygons.append(poly)
        
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# now cycle thorugh all available polygons
for poly in polygons:  
    polygon = Poly3DCollection(poly, alpha=0.5, 
                               facecolors=rng.uniform(0,1,3),
                               linewidths=0.5,edgecolors='black')
    ax.add_collection3d(polygon)
 
# simply setting the plot limits doesn't help
ax.set_xlim([0,1])
ax.set_ylim([0,1])
ax.set_zlim([0,1])

plt.savefig("Voronoi_3D_3.jpg",bbox_inches='tight',dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

[Incomplete Voronoi plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGCk3.jpg)

As you can see, the Voronoi cells are not cut at the edges of the plot, and Voronoi cells that have undefined vertices are not plotted. Something similar to the approach in scipy.spatial.plot_voronoi_2d would have to be applied here - only in 3D.